# Oracle JDBC connection : Transaction Isolation Level

Tags: java, oracle11g, spring-jdbc, transaction-isolation

In my application I am using javax.sql.DataSource to for the org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate instance to connect to **Oracle** Datasource

Now when I inspect the connection parameters for this Oracle connection, I see the ***trasactionIsolation*** level property as 2 [attached screenshot]

[image]

Now what is this **2** value maps to? How can I figure out what is the exact isolation level for transaction out of the mentioned isolation levels in the database.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2005/05-nov/o65asktom-082389.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`java.sql.Connection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html) interface has constants for the different isolation levels that you can compare the number against or that you can use to set the right isolation level, if required.